# Clear timers on hubot reload all scripts

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, hubot

So I have a hubot plugin I'm writing that reminds users at various intervals to do something.  I have a setInterval function that just runs every 5 minutes to do something.  The issue is when I use the 'reload all scripts' command (from here: https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/reload.coffee) it starts a new interval without clearing the old one.  I'm not sure how to best go about clearing the old intervals.  All of my pointers get overwritten when the script is reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mark Lorenz](https://github.com/dapplebeforedawn) ended up showing me the solution for this.  I emitted an event on the robot when reloading scripts, then listened for that event in the script and killed any timeouts.

in reload.coffee ([PR Submitted](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/pull/1505))

```
reloadAllScripts = (msg, success, error) ->
  robot = msg.robot
  robot.emit('reload_scripts')
  scriptsPath = Path.resolve ".", "scripts"
  robot.load scriptsPath
```

in my script

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.on 'reload_scripts', () ->
    clearInterval(Timer) if Timer
```